# SQL FOR JSON: Create line for each object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I'm currently working on a JSON creation on a SQL Server 2016. For this, I use the FOR JSON function.

```
SELECT TOP 2       
      '12.00'            AS [time]
      ,GUID              AS [ID]
      ,'action value'    AS [EVENT.ACTION]
      ,'category value'  AS [EVENT.CATEGORY]
      ,'username'        AS [user.name]  
  FROM TABLE_NAME
 FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

This piece of code creates me this:

```
{"time":"12.00","ID":"16AE8C15-084C-4C84-8F5D-0000193F8E74","EVENT":{"ACTION":"action value","CATEGORY":"category value"},"user":{"name":"username"}},{"time":"12.00","ID":"D5667AF4-5922-4D30-9C8A-00001AB928F6","EVENT":{"ACTION":"action value","CATEGORY":"category value"},"user":{"name":"username"}}
```

The problem is, every object gets displayed on line 1, but I would like to have one line per object.
This would look like this:

```
{"time":"12.00","ID":"16AE8C15-084C-4C84-8F5D-0000193F8E74","EVENT":{"ACTION":"action value","CATEGORY":"category value"},"user":{"name":"username"}},
{"time":"12.00","ID":"D5667AF4-5922-4D30-9C8A-00001AB928F6","EVENT":{"ACTION":"action value","CATEGORY":"category value"},"user":{"name":"username"}}
```

I have not found any snippets to do this. How can I create such a

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build a separate JSON object *for each row*, you may try the following statement:

```
SELECT TOP 2
   (
   SELECT
      '12.00'            AS [time]
      ,GUID              AS [ID]
      ,'action value'    AS [EVENT.ACTION]
      ,'category value'  AS [EVENT.CATEGORY]
      ,'username'        AS [user.name]  
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   ) AS JsonData
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

But, if the expected ouput is one JSON array (with or without array wrapper) for the entire table, the format of this output is controlled by `FOR JSON AUTO`. The visual representation of this output (*one line per each JSON object*) should be made in the presentation  layer. Of course, as an additional option using T-SQL, a small string manipulation is a possible solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE (
   (
   SELECT TOP 2       
      '12.00'            AS [time]
      ,GUID              AS [ID]
      ,'action value'    AS [EVENT.ACTION]
      ,'category value'  AS [EVENT.CATEGORY]
      ,'username'        AS [user.name]  
   FROM TABLE_NAME
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   ),
   '},{',
   '},' + CHAR(10) + '{'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a subquery joining the same table.

```sql
WITH cte_base as (
  SELECT TOP 2       
      '12.00'            AS [time]
      ,GUID              AS [ID]
      ,'action value'    AS [EVENT.ACTION]
      ,'category value'  AS [EVENT.CATEGORY]
      ,'username'        AS [user.name]  
  FROM TABLE_NAME
)
SELECT 
(SELECT b.* FROM cte_base b WHERE a.ID = b.ID FOR JSON AUTO) as JsonData 
FROM cte_base a
```